# Why Toast.setGravity() is not working

Tags: android, android-toast

Hello guys I have 2 versions of Toast like this

version 1:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0).show();
```

version 2:

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
      t.show();
```

Version 2 works fine but version 1 is not.
it gives error cannot resolve method show().
what is going wrong here?

when I write version 1 removing setGravity() method then it works fine

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

can you guys explain it.

Comment: because setGravity dont return Toast type.

Comment: can you please explain it in more detail. and why t.setgravity() works and but version 1 not.

Comment: because makeText return type is Toast, So you can access static methods of Toast class. but setGravity have return type void.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.back_not_allowed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)` returns a `Toast` instance so you can call `show()` function on it, but `Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.back_not_allowed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` returns `void` so you can't use `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0)` over it. This is the reason you have to get the instance of `Toast` in a variable and then use it.

Answer (score 13):

I was just attempting this while trying to do the extended challenge in the book, [Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch](https://amzn.to/2T6ENtY)

Then I looked up the official docs and learned it is ignored now.

From the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/Toast#setgravity), this is a no-op (no operation) when run on newer Android versions.

These are changes that have occurred since the original post.

[image: gravity.setGravity is no-op]